# Shift down one row then rename the column

Tags: python, pandas

My data is looking like this:

```
pd.read_csv('/Users/admin/desktop/007538839.csv').head()

    105586.18
0   105582.910
1   105585.230
2   105576.445
3   105580.016
4   105580.266
```

I want to move that 105568.18 to the 0 index because now it is the column name. And after that I want to name this column 'flux'. I've tried

```
pd.read_csv('/Users/admin/desktop/007538839.csv', sep='\t', names = ["flux"])
```

but it did not work, probably because the dataframe is not in the right format. 
How can I achieve that?

Comment: `because the dataframe is not in the right format.` - Can you explain  more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your code working very nice:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""105586.18
105582.910
105585.230
105576.445
105580.016
105580.266"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to '/Users/admin/desktop/007538839.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep='\t', names = ["flux"])

print (df)
         flux
0  105586.180
1  105582.910
2  105585.230
3  105576.445
4  105580.016
5  105580.266
```

For overwrite original file with same data with new header `flux`:

```
df.to_csv('/Users/admin/desktop/007538839.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it didn't work because I am actually trying to write this df back to the original csv file. So when I used read_csv() to read the file again I found nothing changed. My bad! Can you show me how to overwrite the original file with this new df?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df=pd.read_csv('/Users/admin/desktop/007538839.csv',header=None)
df.columns=['flux']
```

`header=None` is the friend of yours.